# How to go from a worpress blog to a worpress website

Tags: wordpress

I've initialize a wordpress blog, but it was an error because i'm looking for a wordpress website initialization. 
How can i go from a **worpress blog** initializing to a **wordpress website** ?

Comment: check out this link, may it will help you.
https://www.quora.com/How-do-you-convert-a-blog-into-a-website-on-WordPress

Answer (score 2):

They are one and the same, the only difference is setting a static home page.

After creating your home page you go to "Setting > Reading" and change the option "Your homepage displays" to static, in the dropdown under "Homepage" select the page you want to use.